# Вывод данных из контроллера в шаблон Angular js

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, http, spa

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь сделать SPA приложение на Django + Angular, настроил  REST API и как только добрался до публичной части наткнулся на проблему: Angular отказывается подгружать данные из контроллера в шаблон.
Я упростил клиентское приложение до максимума, но проблемы это не решило:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('uniApp', []);
app.controller('uniController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.message = "some text";
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="uniApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>UNI DIGIT</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="uniController">
 <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <script src="{% static 'js/shared/angular-ui-router.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/restangular/latest/restangular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Файловая структура:**

```
main/
--static/
  --js/
    --app.js    
--templates/
  --main/
    --index.html
```

Когда пытаюсь сделать то же самое без Джанго - всё работает, может именно в нём дело. Но ведь Джанго просто отдаёт хтмл-страницу и нужные скрипты...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совсем забыл про тег {% verbatim %}, перед использованием шаблонного синтаксиса Ангуляра.

Comment: Предполагаю это ответ?

Comment: Совершенно верно